Puppeteer hangs on waitForSelector on production (google maps)
I'm using Pupeteer to pull data from google maps.
it's working perfectly on my local machine,however after pulling to production I ended up on the following error
Error during scraping: ProtocolError: Waiting for selector .wiI7pd failed: Runtime.callFunctionOn timed out. Increase the 'protocolTimeout' setting in launch/connect calls for a higher timeout if needed
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


const getReviews = async (url, output = "json") => {
    url = "https://maps.app.goo.gl/EXgBhBRtwxgW9WZ5A"
    output = output.toLowerCase();
    if (output !== "json" && output !== "object") {
        console.error('INVALID OUTPUT OPTION');
        return;
    }

    url = url.toString();
    let browser;
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitForSelector('.wiI7pd',{timeout : 0});
        const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let reviewAuthorNamesClasses = document.getElementsByClassName('d4r55');
            let reviewAuthorNames = [];
            for (let elements of reviewAuthorNamesClasses) {
                reviewAuthorNames.push(elements.innerText);
            }
            let datesClasses = document.getElementsByClassName('PIpr3c');
            let dates = [];
            for (let elements of datesClasses) {
                dates.push(elements.innerText);
            }

            let ratingsClasses = document.getElementsByClassName('kvMYJc');
            let ratings = [];
            for (let elements of ratingsClasses) {
                ratings.push(elements.children.length);
            }

            let reviewsContentClasses = document.getElementsByClassName('wiI7pd');
            let reviewsContent = []
            for (let elements of reviewsContentClasses) {
                reviewsContent.push(elements.innerText);
            }
            return {
                reviewAuthorNames,
                dates,
                ratings,
                reviewsContent
            }
        });
        console.log(data)
        console.log('done ! closing browser...')
        browser.close();

        return output === "json" ? JSON.stringify(data) : data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during scraping:', error);
        if (browser) {
            await browser.close();
        }
        throw new Error('Error during scraping');
    }
};

getReviews()

I also tried
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36');

but didn't work..
anyone came across that?
thanks
I tried setting timeout option.
I tried setting user agent
no results..
I also tried
await page.goto(url, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2',  // <-- good practice to wait for page to fully load 
        });


Try debugging it with headless: false. I did a couple of tries and it seems like Google is first asking to accept cookies, meaning you'll need to get passed that page first.
